# website loads wrong on 1 computer only

Tags: windows, cache

I'm trying to figure out why my website loads differently on 1 of my devices only. I'm testing it on a desktop and a laptop both running windows 10, and an android phone. It loads as is supposed to on desktop and phone, but not the laptop. On the laptop, it's loading as it was built a version ago instead of the current version.

I've tried:

- clearing cookies, cache
- installing a different browser and trying to load it on that
- changing internet connection to data
- dns flush

I've had this issue with styles not loading properly unless you do a version string like `v?=1.0`, but it's not a styling issue this time. It's an app built in node with an interface using vue.js. The problem is the html specified in a `.vue` isn't being rendered as defined. Again, the app itself is working fine on every other device, it's only a problem on this one, so it really looks like a caching issue. Does anyone know what else I can try in order to force a refresh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp apparently the issue was Cloudflare cache. I went into my website's Cloudflare dashboard and went to Cache>Configuration>Purge everything. That fixed the issue.